# sort list so that the argument with the highest number is first

Tags: python

**I want to sort my list so that the argument with the highest number is first**

```
my_list = ["George 5", "Jonathan 2", "Kyle 11"]

print(my_list.sort())

desired output: ["Kyle 11", "George 3", "Jonathan 2"]
```

Comment: Is it always a single name with no spaces followed by a space then a number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort with a key function, where the key splits on spaces, gets the last chunk (which should be the number), then parses it as a number:

```py
my_list.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split()[-1]), reverse=True)
```

Comment: @Ian wanted descending order so need to add `reverse=True` keyword

Comment: @J.Warren I've fixed it :)